# Is it possible to build a RESTful server in Unity?

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine

I am working on researching and building a sample game. I want Clients to call REST APIs to the Unity REST server. Then, the server will run some functions according to the REST APIs. For example, when a Client wants to move some object in the  game, a Client can simply call REST API to the unity server and then the server will run functions in order to move that object.

From my understanding, Unity can be a REST client where we can send GET and POST to the existing REST server by using UnityWebRequest in Unity.Network. However, I would like to know if is it possible to build a REST server within Unity? Or is there any third-party package to support this?

If possible, please kindly give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

So from my understanding, you want to build your REST Server inside unity.

OWIN/Katana Project is only support for .net 4.0 after searching from internet, but unity just support .net 3.5 at the moment, but of course there's experiment feature in unity that allow us to use net 4.6 (this is still experimental feature)

besides of OWIN, there's SignalIR Client that targeted for Net 2.0
which i found here https://github.com/NVentimiglia/SignalR-Unity3d

So this way you have the ability to make REST API Server in Unity.
But why would you make this in unity?

If you want to call the REST API from unity, you already have that ability by using WWW class, that make web request from unity, with get or even post method.
and this allow you to receive text, image, even byte data from that request.

For Example
if you have your REST written with OWIN in some self hosted owin.
and you want to move your player based on what server want.

you can call the api, and then receive some information of three floating point stored as JSON object, that you can then read or cast to vector3.

maybe the reason why you want to build the REST in unity is you need the UnityEngine Feature for doing something.

so, yes unity can be REST client by using WWW or UnityWebRequest.
but can unity be the server is still questionable for me.

This some example of calling my api from unity

```
IEnumerator GetUserInfo (int id)
{
    //the Form Post
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("frameCount", Time.frameCount.ToString());
    //the GET
    WWW www = new WWW ("http://myapi.com:33/user/" + id, form)

    //the request
    yield return wwww;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
        print(www.error);
    }
    else {
        print("Get reply : " + www.text);
    }
}
```

CMIIW

Comment: Thank you a lot for your information. It is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is having a backend for this and websocket is faster because you have a persist connection with the client (It's more useful for realtime games). But if you want to use HTTP requests you can use the following package of Unity: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/rest-client-for-unity-102501

And you can have your backend with other technologies like NodeJS or C# with the latest features using Web API, etc

Best regards